# Magento not navigating to search result page

Tags: magento, search

Any idea why my magento search is not navigating to the search result page at all. it just refreshes the page every time submit is clicked.

heres the link to the website http://remas.com.au

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is http://remas.com.au/catalogsearch/result/?q=neoguri (when query is neoguri). When the form is submitted, a GET request is made to the indexAction of Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController:

```
/**
 * Display search result
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $query = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery();
    /* @var $query Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query */

    $query->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

    if ($query->getQueryText() != '') {
        if (Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->isMinQueryLength()) {
            $query->setId(0)
                ->setIsActive(1)
                ->setIsProcessed(1);
        }
        else {
            if ($query->getId()) {
                $query->setPopularity($query->getPopularity()+1);
            }
            else {
                $query->setPopularity(1);
            }

            if ($query->getRedirect()){
                $query->save();
                $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($query->getRedirect());
                return;
            }
            else {
                $query->prepare();
            }
        }

        Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->checkNotes();

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
        $this->renderLayout();

        if (!Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->isMinQueryLength()) {
            $query->save();
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
}
```

It looks like $query->getQueryText() is null or empty

```
if ($query->getQueryText() != '') {
    ...
}
else {
    $this->_redirectReferer();
}
```

so the action redirects back to the page it was submitted from. If you have a debugger, set a breakpoint at the top of the method

```
$query = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery();
```

and inspect the $query object. You can also dump the object. If this doesn't tell you anything, continue digging. This is the getQuery method of the catalogsearch helper (Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data):

```
/**
 * Retrieve query model object
 *
 * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query
 */
public function getQuery()
{
    if (!$this->_query) {
        $this->_query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')
            ->loadByQuery($this->getQueryText());
        if (!$this->_query->getId()) {
            $this->_query->setQueryText($this->getQueryText());
        }
    }
    return $this->_query;
}
```

and the getQueryText method:

```
/**
 * Retrieve search query text
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getQueryText()
{
    if (!isset($this->_queryText)) {
        $this->_queryText = $this->_getRequest()->getParam($this->getQueryParamName());
        if ($this->_queryText === null) {
            $this->_queryText = '';
        } else {
            /* @var $stringHelper Mage_Core_Helper_String */
            $stringHelper = Mage::helper('core/string');
            $this->_queryText = is_array($this->_queryText) ? ''
                : $stringHelper->cleanString(trim($this->_queryText));

            $maxQueryLength = $this->getMaxQueryLength();
            if ($maxQueryLength !== '' && $stringHelper->strlen($this->_queryText) > $maxQueryLength) {
                $this->_queryText = $stringHelper->substr($this->_queryText, 0, $maxQueryLength);
                $this->_isMaxLength = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->_queryText;
}
```

In one of these two methods, some how the query text is set empty.